# time slot for students and teacher

Tags: php, sql

I am looking to set start time for first 20 students of a particular subject
at 9:00 AM and end time 10:00 AM, for the next 20 i want the time for the same subject 10:00 AM- 11 AM , this should happen for each subject, also i want that only 1 teacher for that particular subject should be alloted for each time slot,

i have tried a lot but still unable to come up with the solution.

user_table

```
user_id | user_name | contact_no | password | flag

6 | Abhis     |  123456788 |      123 | s      
5 | Abhish    |  123456789 |      123 | s    
8 | Sneha     | 1111111111 |      123 | s     
7 | Snehil    | 1111112222 |      123 | s    
1 | Narsingh  | 1234567890 |      123 | t     
2 | Abhinav   | 1234567891 |     1234 | t     
3 | Abhi      | 1234567892 |      123 | s   
4 | Abhishek  | 1234567893 |      123 | s
```

subject_table

```
sub_id | sub_name     
3 | CSS  
1 | HTML    
2 | JQUERY

enr_id | sub_id | user_id | date       | 

1 |      1 |       1 | 2016-04-01 |    
2 |      2 |       1 | 2016-04-01 |    
3 |      3 |       1 | 2016-04-01 |     
4 |      1 |       5 | 2016-04-01 |     
5 |      1 |       6 | 2016-04-01 |    
6 |      1 |       7 | 2016-04-01 |     
7 |      1 |       2 | 2016-04-01 |     
8 |      2 |       2 | 2016-04-01 |
```

Comment: You must have tried something huh , can you show it please

Comment: select st.sub_name, (Case when Count(Student)<=20) AS start_time=9:00 limit 20